# How to Use Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I want to use *Universal Image Loader* library in my project I am using `ImageLoader` but it's not working well.
I have to use for grid view and User Profile Image. My `ImageLoader` is not working and is giving me a size problem.

Please tell me how to use Univarsel Library in my project .

here Is my Activity For Profile

```
// ImageLoader class instance
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext(),
            Welcome.this);

    image.setTag(image_url);

// whenever you want to load an image from url
// call DisplayImage function
// url - image url to load
// loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
// image - ImageView 
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, Welcome.this, image);
```

Above code used In my profile activity.

I want to know if I am adding Univarsal Image Loader Library.

What code I have to use to load image from url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  doption=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.home_icon)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.home_icon)
                    .cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(8)).build();

         ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
         String imagepath= "http:...";
            imageLoader.displayImage(imagepath,ImageViewinstance, doption);
```

Comment: Sakir Bro this Methode Can use Univarsal library ?

Comment: U need to get instace of class first

Comment: And Nothing To At all in Code??
if Dont Want to chnge i m going To use

Answer (score 1):

[**Picasso**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw9nS.png) allows for hassle-free image loading in your application—often in one line of code!

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled automatically by [**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

- Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
- Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
- Automatic memory and disk caching.

[image]

Comment: thnxx Chirag Bro ..This One Is Also Want to Use for GridView Of USers

How TO use For Gridview

Comment: use this in getView method of baseadapter class ....gridview example is... [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)